How to make a VSTACK function that skips certain rows (Repeated rows)
I have to combine the rows from two different tables (Tabel 1 and 2).

Table 1:







Original
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed




ID
Apply
From node
To node
Link type
Link type
Height [m]
Width [m]
Diameter [m]
Length [m]
Material ID


a
TRUE
N10908K
N10140K
Circular
Rec
50
60
1
11
Stone


c
TRUE
N10090K
N10070K
Circular
Rec
51
61
2
22
Stone


f
TRUE
F253_1
N10100K
Circular
Rec
52
62
3
33
Stone


cc
TRUE
cc
ccc
Egg shape
Rec
53
63
4
44
Stone


dd
TRUE
dd
ddd
Egg shape
Rec
54
64
5
55
Stone



Table 2:



ID
Apply
From node
To node
Apply
Link type
Height [m]
Width [m]
Diameter [m]
Length [m]
Material ID
Material ID
Material ID




aa
TRUE
aa
aaa
TRUE
Egg shape


0,3
83,18
Iron
Iron
Iron


bb
TRUE
bb
bbb
TRUE
Egg shape


0,9
100,6
Iron
Iron
Iron


cc
TRUE
cc
ccc
TRUE
Egg shape


0,5
72,55
Iron
Iron
Iron


dd
TRUE
dd
ddd
TRUE
Egg shape


0,235
5,15
Iron
Iron
Iron



However, the challenge is that I have changed certain ways for some of the rows in a separate table (Edited tabel). Moreover, the "edited tabel" does not contain the same columns.

Edited:







Original
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed
Changed




ID
Apply
From node
To node
Link type
Link type
Height [m]
Width [m]
Diameter [m]
Length [m]
Material ID


a
TRUE
N10908K
N10140K
Circular
Rec
50
60
1
11
Stone


c
TRUE
N10090K
N10070K
Circular
Rec
51
61
2
22
Stone


f
TRUE
F253_1
N10100K
Circular
Rec
52
62
3
33
Stone


cc
TRUE
cc
ccc
Egg shape
Rec
53
63
4
44
Stone


dd
TRUE
dd
ddd
Egg shape
Rec
54
64
5
55
Stone



So I need a function that combines "table 1" and "table 2", but at the same time skips the rows that have been listed in the "edited table", and returns these from the "edited table" instead. Moreover I need to fill out the correct values in the different columns for the correct ID.
The real IDs consist of both numbers and letters - and in a few cases symbols.
This is how the export table should look like:

I have tried to use the following function, where that should be a "delete" part, but that didnot work at all.
=IF(COUNTA(DY6:DY12)<=2; VSTACK(FILTER(DK5:DK15; (DK5:DK15<>"")*(DK5:DK15<>DK5)*(ISERROR(MATCH(DK5:DK15; DY6:DY12; )))); FILTER(DK18:DK23; (DK18:DK23<>"")*(DK18:DK23<>DK18)*(ISERROR(MATCH(DK18:DK23; DY6:DY12; ))))); VSTACK(FILTER(DK5:DK15; (DK5:DK15<>"")*(DK5:DK15<>DK5)*(ISERROR(MATCH(DK5:DK15; DY6:DY12; )))); FILTER(DK18:DK23; (DK18:DK23<>"")*(DK18:DK23<>DK18)*(ISERROR(MATCH(DK18:DK23; DY6:DY12; )))); FILTER(DY6:DY12; (DY6:DY12<>"")*(DY6:DY12<>DY6)*(DY6:DY12<>DY6))))

I would use this to find IDs that are in "Edited Table": https://exceljet.net/formulas/extract-common-values-from-two-lists, but why in Table1 and Table2, there are 3 columns called "Material ID", but in "Edited Table", there is only one column called "Material ID"?

Below should work for you:
=LET(
    original_tables; VSTACK(DK6:DW14; DK19:DW22);
    ids; INDEX(original_tables; ; 1);
    edited_table; IFERROR(HSTACK(DY7:EB11; ""; ED7:EI11; ""; ""); "");
    edited_ids; INDEX(edited_table; ; 1);
    included; ISERROR(XMATCH(ids; edited_ids; 0; 1));
    filtered_original_table; FILTER(original_tables; included; "");
    res; VSTACK(filtered_original_table; edited_table);
    IF(res = ""; ""; res)
)

VSTACK(DK6:DW14; DK19:DW22) combines table1 and table2.
IFERROR(HSTACK(DY7:EB11; ""; ED7:EI11; ""; ""); "") chooses the columns needed in Edited Table.
ISERROR(XMATCH(ids; edited_ids; 0; 1) checks which IDs are not included in "Edited Table".
FILTER(original_tables; included; "") filters out IDs that are in the "Editied Table"
VSTACK(filtered_original_table; edited_table) combines the filtered table1+table2 and Edited Table.

You can change edited_table to IFERROR(HSTACK(DY7:EB11; ""; ED7:EI11; ""; ""); ""). I updated my in my answer post.

Is there any compelling reason you cannot keep your "Edited Table" columns fixed? What you want can be achieved by using MS functions such asREDUCE. but I would rather not go down that rabbit hole, unless you really like mega MS365 formulas that you cannot understand easily.

Or just take a look at @nkalvi answer. Since you will have to use lambda anyway.

If using Microsoft 365, convert these to tables with unique column headers,

and define these helper functions under 'Define Names'
fxLookup2=
=LAMBDA(from_table1, from_table2,  
LET(id, TableExport[@[ID]:[ID]], 
table1_value, XLOOKUP(id, Table1[ID], from_table1, NA()),  
table2_value, XLOOKUP(id, Table2[ID], from_table2, NA()),  
IF(ISNA(table1_value),table2_value, table1_value)))

fxLookup3=
=LAMBDA(from_corrected, from_table1, from_table2,  
LET(corrected_value, XLOOKUP(TableExport[@[ID]:[ID]], TableCorrected[ID], from_corrected, NA()),  
IF(ISNA(corrected_value), fxLookup2(from_table1, from_table2), corrected_value)))

then use calculated columns for the export table:

For the ID column in the corrected table, you could paste the values (only) from =VSTACK(Table1[ID],Table2[ID]) from another location.
Result for with a couple of entries:

